# Click Once in Windows 10 NotifyIcon not displaying

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce, notifyicon, windows-10

So using the following diagram:
[image: Working]

You can see that the only time when anything breaks is when I use ClickOnce in Windows 10, however the notifications work perfectly fine if I run it directly from the exe. When I run it using ClickOnce using the console I can see the same methods get hit in the console but the notifications don't show up. I have tried to get this fixed for a very long time now with no avail.

The click once is deployed to a network share. The ClickOnce notifications work fine on Windows 8. I have absolutely no idea what could be causing this.

Comment: Well considering Windows 10 is not publicly released yet, I would be that things will still be changing in the future.

Comment: It is still coming out pretty darn soon, but it still doesn't make sense why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Well unfortunately, Microsoft, like many businesses, tends not to release official documentation on changes (like this) until the product is prepared for roll-out.

Comment: You can solve this by using toast notifications from Windows 8 and above.
Here is an explanation how to use the ToastNotificationManager in a Windows Forms Application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486460/showing-windows-8-toast-from-windows-forms-app

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a0d651dc-e687-45ae-9304-932890a0a026/no-notifications-on-windows-10-when-deploying-with-clickonce?forum=winformssetup    just found that, hopefully this gets fixed...

Answer (score 0):

So got into discussion with someone I know at Microsoft and it looks like in the latest version (that he said should be released somewhere in November 2015) should contain the fix for this issue.

Waiting it out and hopefully the fix comes, if not I will contact him again and see how things are going as I would say this is a really bad problem.