# Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'Windows.Graphics.Printing3D' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to import `Windows.Graphics.Printing3D`in VB.Net; however, i get the following warning:

> Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'Windows.Graphics.Printing3D' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39141010/17034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out eventually. It can be done by importing these two references:

1 - `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll` located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5`

2 - `Windows.winmd` located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\`

Refer to this [Windows Blog](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#RfvYWEdEHIFWQVyh.97) article for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference an assembly that contains a declaration for at least one type that is a member of that namespace.  Whatever type you're trying to use, open the MSDN documentation page for that type and it will tell you what assembly that is.  You can then reference it on the References page of the project properties.

That said, it appears that that namespace is part of the UWP.  Is this a UWP app that you're building?  If not then that namespace will not be available at all.  If it is then I think you should already have an appropriate reference, which makes me think that it's not.

Comment: No, it's not a UWP app. I was trying to incorporate it in a winforms project. Can I not do that?

Comment: OK thanks, do you think it would be possible to build a UWP project in the same Solution and use it by referencing the UWP project?

Comment: It would not. A UWP-specific library is UWP-specific. A library accessible to all types of apps can only access functionality accessible to all types of apps.