# Reference Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement Namespace in a C# desktop application

Tags: c#, ibeacon

I am trying to add ibeacons to a C# project and it is not going very well.
i tried to follow this example:

> https://blog.cinlogic.com/2017/02/01/getting-started-with-ibeacons-and-windows-10/

but i wasn't able to reference Bluetooth.Advertisement Namespace.
Has anyone here used this namespace in a desktop C# application?

Comment: Crystal ball says that adding the UwpDesktop nuget package did not work out well.  Find manual instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39141010/17034).

Comment: Thanks Hans. i removed UwpDesktop nuget package and added the windowsMD referece manually and then i am able to use the windows namespace down to   Windows.Devices.Bluetooth; but i would need to get down to Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement;  so just missing .Advertisement

Comment: Project > Add Reference > Windows tab, select "Windows.Devices".

Comment: I solved it by adding windowsmd from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.16299.0