# Visual Basic WinForms Displaying Windows10 Toast Notifications Issue

Tags: .net, winforms, notifications

Windows refuses to show my Toast Notification, its probably because my program doesn't have permissions to send them. The only problem is that I can't find a way to give those permissions to the code.

My toast code:

```
Dim toastXML As New Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument
    toastXML.LoadXml("<toast>
                                <visual>
                                    <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
                                        <text>""zz""</text>
                                        <text>""zz""</text>
                                    </binding>
                                </visual>
                              </toast>")
    Dim toast As New ToastNotification(toastXML)
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("toast").Show(toast)
```

Comment: Does the application crash? throw an exception? Does it behave as if nothing went wrong? Looks like your code is based on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-enhance which is the best reference I could find on doing this kind of thing.

Comment: Application does not crash nor it does produce any signs of error. The Toast just doesn't show up.

Comment: Also in most of the examples there is no string in CreateToastNotifier(here), but in my case visual studio refuses to compile if I don't add the string.

Comment: See if this answer helps: [Windows.UI.Notifications is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39141010/719186)