# How do I get access to Windows.Storage namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I want to save data to files for my Microsoft Store app, so I need access to `Windows.Storage` namespace, but it's unclear how I can get it. I couldn't add it as a reference. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with .NET Framework 4.6.1.

My app is a Windows Forms application that I converted to UWP using the Desktop Bridge.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39141010/17034

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The recommended steps to get access to UWP APIs are listed in the dedicated [blog post on Windows Blog](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#vZiZ96PlZUqTduts.97).

Basically you can take two approaches: add the references to UWP dlls and winmd files manually or use the `UwpDesktop-Updated` NuGet package that will take care of this for you automatically, but this project doesn't seem to be up to date with the latest SDKs, so the manual approach may be a better solution for you.

Comment: One step I would add to that answer is I needed to download this SDK: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: NuGet now have an updated package: UwpDesktop-Updated.

Comment: If you're finding this now, you just have to use the proper TFM with .NET 5+, for example see this error message from upgrading from the Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts (which was the replacement from the solution posted above). https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1130

E.g.

`<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>`

Comment: And the `TargetFramework` in the project file is the same as the _Target OS Version_ in the project's properties page, correct? And the minimum required is `10.0.17763.0`, correct? Probably the reason the help page says to edit the project file is that it is easier for the author to explain that.

Answer (score -1):

#### In Visual Studio 2022 and .NET Framework 4.x

I needed to add the nuget package `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` and then I was able to use the `Windows.Storage` namespace.

#### In Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 8

I got an error `netsdk1130`

> < Component name > cannot be referenced. Referencing a Windows Metadata component directly when targeting .NET 5 or higher is not supported.

which leads to that [learn Microsoft page netsdk1130](https://aka.ms/netsdk1130).

So I added (changed) the target framework in my csproj-file like it was suggested there.

`<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>`

and I was able to use the namespace again.