# Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I want to run the Xamarin project and did all the updates. When I run the project I get the following error

> The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

for the lines

```
using Windows.Storage; 
using Windows.ApplicationModel.ExtendedExecution;
```

Comment: when click on error ;it gives error at  using Windows.Storage; using Windows.ApplicationModel.ExtendedExecution;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You haven't even explained which platforms you use and where do you see the error. If you see this error on iOS or Android, it is expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're missing these .dll

The recommended steps to get access to UWP APIs are listed in the dedicated blog post on [Windows Blog](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#vZiZ96PlZUqTduts.97).
Basically you can take two approaches: add the references to UWP dlls and winmd files manually or use the UwpDesktop NuGet package that will take care of this for you automatically.

For more details, you can check: [How do I get access to Windows.Storage namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49688510/how-do-i-get-access-to-windows-storage-namespace)

Answer (score 0):

Not on Xamarin but on net framework 4.8:

ensure you have ref to System.Windows ..... but also to Presentation framework!
nice joke @microsoft!

```
<Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
<Reference Include="System.Windows" />
```