# Toast Notifications in Win Forms .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, winforms, toast

I've searched through a number of different posts to do with creating toast notifications from a Win Form however when these through I get an error when generating the toast notification.

> System.Exception: Element not found. (Exception from
>   HRESULT:0x80070490).

I have edited the csproj file and added the following:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10586</TargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

and added the references to `Windows.Data` and `Windows.UI` and also a reference to `System.Runtime.dll` as per the suggestions in [Windows.UI.Notifications is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139369/windows-ui-notifications-is-missing)

```
using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;
using Windows.UI.Notifications;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;

namespace ToastNotify
{
    class Notify
    {
        public void GenerateToast(string header, string content)
        {
            ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText02;

            XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);

            XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(header));
            toastTextElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(content));

            XmlNodeList toastImageElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
            ((XmlElement)toastImageElements[0]).SetAttribute("src", "..\\..\\Resources\\icon.ico");

            IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
            ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("duration", "long");

            ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);

            try
            {
                ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: Element not found -- Exception means - Some xml element that you are trying to looup is not in the Xml (or not at the xpath where you are expecting)

Comment: Interesting.  As a side note, this code worked when creating a new Universal Windows app however obviously cannot reference a .net core class in a win form.

Comment: Can you debug and pin-point which line the Exception is thrown. Also... put that statement in Watch and see if it resolves there

Comment: The exception is thrown on: ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(),Show(toast);

Comment: Can you check the toastXml is a valid xml before the CreateToastNotifier() is caused. Also I read the msdn page for ToastNotification. Its mostly for UWP. Can be used in DesktopApps but has following requirements:

Comment: Sending toast notifications from desktop apps
Generally, sending a toast notification from a desktop app is the same as sending it from a UWP app. However, you should be aware of these differences and requirements:

For a desktop app to display a toast, the app must have a shortcut on the Start screen.
The shortcut must have an AppUserModelID.
Desktop apps cannot schedule a toast.

Comment: Outputing toastXml before the appending of child records shows: `<toast><visual><binding template="ToastText02"><text id="1"></text><text id="2"></text></binding></visual></toast><toast><visual><binding template="ToastImageAndText02"><image id="1" src=""/><text id="1"></text><text id="2"></text></binding></visual></toast>` and after the values are replaced as expected. My understanding of it too was it was just for UWP apps however came across the link in my question that suggested it was possible

Comment: The AppUserModelId was the missing piece! Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139369/windows-ui-notifications-is-missing

Answer (score 10):

You should explicitly provide `applicationId` for CreateToastNotifier.

Like this:

```
private const String APP_ID = "Microsoft.Samples.DesktopToastsSample";
...
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(APP_ID).Show(toast);
```

But I have bad news. Starting from Windows 10 1709 WinForms applications just does not show toast notifications. Before that Show(toast) was working, but now it neither throw an exception, nor show any toast notification.

I'm still figuring this out.

As noted by Prateek Shrivastava there are (new) limitations.

Have a look here   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationmanager.createtoastnotifier

**Update:**
Here is the step by step guide, to create a setup with APP_ID so notifications will work on *all* Windows 10 versions: 
[Send a local toast notification from desktop C# apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop)

**Update:**
It works again in Windows 10 1903 without setup.

Comment: from where can i get the applicationId if i am developing a local solution?

Comment: @Ali123 the Application ID is custom. You make it up. It's the string you're using to register your app that's why they suggest using `companyname/product name` so that it doesn't conflict. Ultimately, while that MS sample link above seems pretty complete it's trash. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use This and make sure you are setting the Image (**Icon**) full path if you want to show an icon otherwise just pass null.

```
public static void GenerateToast(string appid, string imageFullPath, string h1, string h2, string p1)
{

    var template = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText04);

    var textNodes = template.GetElementsByTagName("text");

    textNodes[0].AppendChild(template.CreateTextNode(h1));
    textNodes[1].AppendChild(template.CreateTextNode(h2));
    textNodes[2].AppendChild(template.CreateTextNode(p1));

    if (File.Exists(imageFullPath))
    {
        XmlNodeList toastImageElements = template.GetElementsByTagName("image");
        ((XmlElement)toastImageElements[0]).SetAttribute("src", imageFullPath);
    }
    IXmlNode toastNode = template.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
    ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("duration", "long");

    var notifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(appid);
    var notification = new ToastNotification(template);

    notifier.Show(notification);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to chime in here, because I'm working on a WinForms app (.Net Framework 4.7*) that's failing to build on a GitHub build worker because at some point, support for toast notifications was hacked in with some weird references to these WinMetadata\Windows.*.winmd files.

Woe be to anyone who has found this StackOverflow question.

You're probably targeting the .Net Framework 4.x because you're working on a Win Forms app. [.Net Framework 4.8 is supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements) on Windows 7, and Windows 7 does not have [ToastNotifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification?view=winrt-10240) which is probably the class you're looking for. Hence the problem.

I think the only solution is the one [in the updated answer that's most upvoted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=uwp), which is just target the more modern UWP framework that will only work on Windows 10 and up. But you're still trying to send toast notifications from a framework that's not designed to support it. At some point in your code, you're probably doing a check if the platform you're running on is Windows 10 or newer. Not even a compiler statement, just straight up C# or VB.Net. That's not how the .Net Framework is designed to work - it's meant to be platform-agnostic.

My only advice is; setup a new build target for Windows 10+ and setup your project following the [advice from Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52166068/530172). That should be the least-hackish way of making WinForms do neat Windows 10 tricks.