# C# .NET UserNotificationListener element not found

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, notifications, toast

I'm trying to hook into the UserNotificationListener in order to intercept Windows 10 Notifications however I'm unable to hook the event itself nor retrieve the notifications directly without the event.
I need this to run in a Winforms application and not UWP application but unfortunately the microsoft docs explain how to do this only for UWP. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener)

```
private async void checkUserNotificationListenerAccess()
    {
        if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.Notifications.Management.UserNotificationListener"))
        {
            listener = UserNotificationListener.Current;
            UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus accessStatus = await listener.RequestAccessAsync();
            try
            {
                listener.NotificationChanged += Listener_NotificationChanged;
                Debug.WriteLine("Listener Hooked");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var access_status = UserNotificationListener.Current.GetAccessStatus();
                Debug.WriteLine("Notifications Hook failed");
            }
        }
    }
```

The Exception always fires giving the error "Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)". The variable access_status returns "Allowed".

I have manually added the references System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime and Windows.winmd in order to get it to build successfully and I am running this on Windows 10 Build 19042.789.

Does anybody have any idea on how to sort this out?

EDIT: I've managed to sort this out. I've recreated my project using .NET Core 3.1 as that had an easier process for having the libraries I needed. The main step however that I had to take to solve this problem was to create an MSIX installer for the application (Windows Application Packaging Project within Visual Studio). When the app is installed with the installer configured as per Microsoft instructions link I posted above, it then works.

Comment: Does this help you?[Toast Notifications in Win Forms .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51374101/toast-notifications-in-win-forms-net-4-5)

Comment: I'm extremely surprised you managed to get ANYTHING working.  The Microsoft/Windows development process is a complete shambles imho.

Comment: Erik - to get all this chimpness working - you may be getting "Access denied" when you try and define the event handler.  If this is the case (!) then check the package manifest for your project (if you have one and./or if you can find it) and make sure Capability "User Notifications" is checked.  Other than that ... you're as lost and as desperate as I am ...