# Catch Exception Message without stopping

Tags: vb.net, exception

I have a simple Try Catch function like:

```
Try
'do that
Catch
'didn't work now try again
End Try
```

Now I want the Error / Catch Message to be displayed as Messagebox which works with:

```
Catch ex As Exception
Messagebox.Show(ex.message)
```

The issue with that is that it always Stops / Quits the Application after showing me the Error Message which I want to prevent. This should try something until it works and always display the error message without stopping. Is that possible? I need it as compiled exe so just Debugging won't be an option.

**As Explanation what I am trying to do:**
Basically I have a Timer that executes every 10 Seconds a Request to my Server. It check if my Server is up and connected. If it can't reach my Server it should exactly display me the Message why it didn't connect but it shouldn't stop, it should continue pinging my server 10 seconds later again and try again until it works. The thing is that the exception message sometimes changes so I really need the Exception Message as output

Comment: This is `vb.net` not `c#`. Also worth mentioning, don't use catch statements to depict code/program flow, it's bad design. I feel as well, you've left out important code that *could be the root cause* of what you're experiencing.

Comment: It doesn't matter if vb.net or c# as both can be converted to either one of them. I can convert code from c# over to vb.net and also the other way around. 
Yes I've left out "important" code because it would confuse too much as it is a simple question how to output an exception message without stopping there. Its not necessary to show any further code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like right now you have a method that sometimes throws like this:

```
 Public Sub CheckServer()
    ' do something to test the server
 End Function
```

If the code is not isolated to it's own method like that, *it should be*.

And you want to call it like this:

```
Try 
    CheckServer()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(...)
End Try
```

I suggest moving the Try/Catch inside the method and making it return a value:

```
 Public Function CheckServer() As String
    Try
        ' do something to test the server
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
    Return String.Empty
 End Function
```

And then call it like this:

```
Dim errorMessage As String = CheckServer()
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage) Then
     SendAlert(errorMessage)
End If
```

Where you also have a separate alert method:

```
Public Sub SendAlert(alertText As String)
    SomeControl.Text += $"{Now} -- {alertText}{vbCrLf}"
End Sub
```

Notice I did not use `MessageBox`, because it blocks your UI. But the idea here is this makes it easy to change what you want to do with the alerts when they come in. For example, you might [create a toast notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51374101/toast-notifications-in-win-forms-net-4-5).

Since you're using WinForms, the other thing you could do here is define and then raise an event, rather than returning a value.

Comment: Well it is a bit more complex. Basically I have a Timer that executes every 10 Seconds a Request to my Server. It check if my Server is up and connected. If it can't reach my Server it should exactly display me the Message why it didn't connect but it shouldn't stop, it should continue pinging my server 10 seconds later again and try again until it works. The thing is that the exception message sometimes changes so I really need the Exception Message as output.

Comment: Okay. You know that `MessageBox` will block program flow on the UI thread until you respond, right?

Comment: Yes I know that. I tried it with outputting it as console message but I didn't get it to work for my (not console) windows form application.

Comment: Okay I guess this could work. I will try it and give you a response. Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: Display the error message in the status bar or in a label instead of using the message box.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using TCPClient to connect ???  If you are,  you can just write an IsConnected code.  TCP client stays connected until the server or client go out.

The most common error message when a server is not accepting connections is the “server did not properly respond in time message”

Constantly sending the server a request isn’t ideal.   You need a one notification to come through when the connection is lost... and then set the timer to constantly try to reconnect.