# Click Event of Notification in Windows 10 Notificationcenter

Tags: winforms

I'm using a NotifyIcon to show a Ballontip.
Clicking the Ballontip fires an action.

If the Ballontip times out, it stays in the Win10 Notification center.
Is there a way to catch the click event of that notification, once it shows in the notification center?

Answer (score 0):

Found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39141010/1944848

It is a hacky way to add Windows.Data and the Windows.UI dependency from UWP to winforms.
You get access to ToastNotificationManager class then and can register to the [Activated Event of the ToastNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.activated)