# Sending UWP Toastnotification fails in WinForm app due to System.IO.FileNotFoundException in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, uwp, toast

I am building a WinForm app with vb.net (Target .Net 4.7.2) and I want to Push a ToastNotification from the Windows UI Toolkit.

What I did so far:
I installed the following references from NuGet:

- Microsoft.Toolkit.UWP.Notifications (6.0.0)
- Microsoft.Toolkit.UWP.UI.Controls (6.0.0)
- Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts (10.0.18362.2005)
- System.Runtime (4.3.1)
- System.Runtime.InteropServices (4.3.0)
- Microsoft.Windows.WinMD (1.0.191022.1)

I am building the notification with the following function

```
    Private Sub CreatePush()
    Try
        Dim template = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText04)
        Dim textNodes = template.GetElementsByTagName("text")
        textNodes.Item(0).InnerText = title
        textNodes.Item(1).InnerText = content
        Dim imagePath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Resources\harddrive_white.png"
        Dim imageNode = template.GetElementsByTagName("image")
        CType(imageNode.Item(0), Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement).SetAttribute("src", imagePath)

        Dim notifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("appnamehere")
        Dim Notification = New ToastNotification(template)
        Notification.Tag = id
        AddHandler Notification.Activated, AddressOf Clicked
        AddHandler Notification.Dismissed, AddressOf Dismissed
        AddHandler Notification.Failed, AddressOf ToastFailed
        notifier.Show(Notification)
    Catch ex As Exception
        newLog("Failed showing toast notification. " & ex.Message, LogType.Exception)
        MsgBox(content, MsgBoxStyle.Information, title)
    End Try
End Sub
```

When running the Function, the application halts and shows a System.io.Filenotfound exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "The file or assembly "System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" or a dependency on it was not found. The system cannot find the specified file."

I have already followed the instructions form here
[Windows.UI.Notifications is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139369/windows-ui-notifications-is-missing) but this did not help.
Is there any experience in building a winform app with Win10 ToastNotifications?
The code builds without errors, but shows a warning that there is a versionconflict of the system.runtime package (reinstalling did not help).

Comment: [Send a local toast notification from desktop C# apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop)

Comment: @Jimi I have seen this documentation and followed along, but I get stuck at the second part for adding the references. If I try to reference to Windows.Data, the reference window stays empty inside the Windows tab and tells me that there were no references found inside the Windows Universal SDK

Comment: Browse to the assemblies repositories, as shown in the documentation, to add the references manually. So you can see whether you're missing something. Pick the latest Kit, same versions. (Also, assuming you have an actual `AppID`, not just `appnamehere`)

Comment: I am referencing to the latest `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>` and `<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.18362.0</TargetPlatformVersion>`. The window still stays empty (see here https://imgur.com/a/gbFoa1c).

Comment: Follow the steps described in the Docs, plus use this sample Project: [WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts) (`WPF/C#`), also following the steps described there to verify the installation status of the required packages. In case something is missing, see the former linked documentation, the section related to the installation of the NuGet packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "The file or assembly
>   "System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.3.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" or a dependency on
>   it was not found. The system cannot find the specified file."

This error means it can't find System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime file, by testing, you can add reference about this dll file.

**Right-click the project > Add Reference > Browse**, I chose this file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.7.2\Facades path(note that you need to find this folder based on your actual situation), then find **System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll** and add it.

Comment: Well after a long time I figured out, that using the NuGet package System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime messed up the reference to the local runtime I used before. After removing the NuGet and local reference, and then re-adding the local reference, it worked again! Thanks!