# Winforms - Action Center Balloon/Toast click

Tags: c#, winforms, toast, balloon-tip

I have a winforms app and working with C#.
When my app starts, it looks for updates using AutoUpdater.NET and then shows a Balloontip notifying the user of updates.
When the Balloontip is clicked, a `BalloonTip_Click` event is fired.
All good... except.
When the Balloontip is ignored it goes into Action Center (As normal behavior in Win 10).
How on earth do I get the BalloonTip_Click event from Action Center?!
I have tried using Toast Notifications, and doing `toast.Activated += Toast_Activated` works when shown (just like Balloontip),
but again I get no Click Event in Action Center.

Why I want this? When my customers might go into Action Center and see "Update Available", and missed it the first time, when they click on it, it will bring my app to front and open the Update Dialog.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: [Send a local toast notification from desktop C# apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop) (the COM server part is what you probably want to read first). -- [WindowsNotifications /
desktop-toasts - GitHub](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts)  -- Also: [Windows.UI.Notifications is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39141010/7444103)