# using Windows.UI.Notifications not found

Tags: c#, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I've been recently assigned to a new C# project that use the "Windows.UI.Notifications;" to access the "ToastNotificationManager". However the previous dev is not reachable and I can't access any documentation about how is it supposed to work.
I've seen a few question about the dll, and tried to follow this one "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139369/windows-ui-notifications-is-missing" but I'm blocked to this step

> Open the Winforms project, use Project > Add Reference > Windows tab > tick the Windows.Data and the Windows.UI contract. Add Reference again and use the Browse tab to select System.Runtime. I picked the one in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\ .NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades. This reference displays with a warning icon, not sure what it is trying to say but it doesn't appear to have any side-effects.

I have nothing in the submenu "Windows" and can't find it elsewhere.

I've installed pretty much everything proposed for VS PRO 2019.

Any idea?