# Error:The type ToastNotification exists in both Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract and Windows.UI

Tags: c#, winforms

I am pretty new to WinForms and I have created a basic WinForm and now I am trying to create a toast notification for my app.I read the microsoft doc for doing the same which is in the link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification?view=winrt-19041

And this is the piece of code I am trying to execute:

```
    protected List<ToastNotification> toastNotificationList = new List<ToastNotification>();
            public void SendToastNotification()
            {
                // Constructs the content
                ToastContent content = new ToastContentBuilder()
                    .AddText("Firing Toast")
                    .GetToastContent();
    
                // Creates the notification
                ToastNotification notification = new ToastNotification(content.GetXml());
    
                //Add an in memory event handler
                notification.Activated += ToastNotificationCallback_Activated;
    
                //Adds toast notification to list to persist toast
                toastNotificationList.Add(notification);
    
                //Sends the notification
                ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(notification);
            }
```

But my code doesn't build and the following error is seen :

> Error CS0433  The type 'ToastNotification' exists in both
> 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=7.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' and
> 'Windows.UI, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'

and a lot of errors with the same description.Can you please help me with resolving this issue?

Comment: Did you try to instantiate type 'ToastNotification' via [Fully qualified names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces#fully-qualified-names)?

Comment: yes..It still throws the same error

Comment: Check the notes here: [Windows.UI.Notifications is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39141010/7444103) and see this implementation: [Desktop Toast - GitHub](https://github.com/CHDKUtil/DesktopToast), for both WinForms and WPF. Note that the sample code in that repo is using a logging library, [Chimp.Logging.Core](https://github.com/CHDKUtil/Chimp.Logging.Core): I don't know what this is used for nor what it does - most probably, it's not needed at all. I suggest you use the sample code alone, as a source of information, or remove that package and its references.

Comment: See also: [Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance) and [Modernize your desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/) (more info in the menu on the left) -- Also: [Windows Community Toolkit Sample App](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-community-toolkit-sample-app/9nblggh4tlcq?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) (and related GitHub repo)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue
I had changed the framework in the project file to

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.17763</TargetFramework>
```

And also added the nuget package Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts

Basically you should do one or the other (the framework change for .NET 5 and above)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with WinForms .NET 4.6.2. I could not figure out how to include Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, so I used reflection instead:

```
var builder = new ToastContentBuilder();
builder.AddText(message);
builder.AddText(header);
this.toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManagerCompat.CreateToastNotifier();

var toastContentBuilderType = builder.GetType();
var toastNotificationType = this.toastNotifier.GetType().GetMethod("Show").GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
var toastNotifierType = this.toastNotifier.GetType();

var content = toastContentBuilderType.GetMethod("GetXml").Invoke(builder, null);

this.toastNotification = toastNotificationType.GetConstructors()[0].Invoke(new[] { content });
toastNotificationType.GetProperty("Group").SetValue(this.toastNotification, "WindowsNotification");
toastNotificationType.GetProperty("Tag").SetValue(this.toastNotification, (string)manifest.Key.Value);
toastNotifierType.GetMethod("Show").Invoke(this.toastNotifier, new[] { this.toastNotification });
```