# Show PopUp Form without stealing focus

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, notifications, focus

I am doing the same thing that this => [Show a Form without stealing focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156046/show-a-form-without-stealing-focus)

I'm using a Form to show notifications (it appears at the bottom right of the screen), but when I show this form it steals the focus from my software and computer. Is there a way to show this "notification" form without stealing focus?

I have tried all solution but when my form is open i loose the focus in all my computer :

My Notification Class :

```
/// <summary>
/// Class to sent Notification like Skype/Outlook
/// </summary>
public partial class Notification : Form
{
    private static readonly List<Notification> OpenNotifications = new List<Notification>();
    private readonly FormAnimator _animator;

    public Notification(...)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Other...
    }

    public void Notification_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // Close the form by sliding down.
        _animator.Duration = 0;
        _animator.Direction = FormAnimator.AnimationDirection.Down;
    }
    
    protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
    {
       get { return true; }
    }
    
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
      get
          {
            CreateParams baseParams = base.CreateParams;
            const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;
            const int WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080;
            baseParams.ExStyle |= ( int )( WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW );
            return baseParams;
          }
   }
    //Other Functions
}
```

}

My InitializeComponent() of Notification From (TopMost is false) :

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        //OTHER
        this.lifeTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.lifeTimer_Tick);
        this.Controls.Add(this.labelTitle);
        this.Controls.Add(this.labelBody);
        this.TopMost = false;
        this.FormClosed += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(this.Notification_FormClosed);
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Notification_Load);
        this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.Notification_Shown);
        this.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Notification_Click);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
```

My Notification form is open using Show :

```
        Notification toastNotification = new Notification(...);
        toastNotification.Show();
```

I know it's a duplicate but i really need your help , thank you :)

Comment: `protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation => true;`. Remove the `CreateParams` override. If you want the *notification* to disappear as soon as it's interacted with, add `this.Close()` in its `OnActivated()` override (don't call `base` either). The *Notification Form* won't steal focus and the current Foreground Window won't change. I'd suggest to implement a standard notification or a proper Toast Notification instead.

Comment: @Jimi thank you for your response , i have tried removing the `CreateParams` override , my notification is closed automatically after a specific duration (Notification_Shown) . 'implement a standard notification or a proper Toast Notification instead' it will be the same code no ? how would you do it ?

Comment: *my notification is closed automatically after a specific duration*: not important. *i have tried removing the CreateParams override*: then? *it will be the same code*: [NotifyIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon) and [Toast notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-desktop-apps) (see also: [Windows.UI.Notifications is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39141010/7444103), just in case...) have nothing to do with the current code.

Comment: Consider https://www.michaelcrump.net/pop-toast-notification-in-wpf/ or https://www.nuget.org/packages/Notification.WPF/

Comment: Thank you @Jimi i have changed my notification to NotifyIcon to make it easy :)

Comment: Well, good to know you've got it to work. See also the Toast notifications, for a *fancier* (customizable) presentation of your notifications (when running on Windows10). The implementation is not really difficult (see Hans Passant's answer to the question I linked).