# Is there a way to create a WinForms application with UWP extension and not the opposite?

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

I have looked at multiple solutions such as "DesktopBridgeToUWP" and "Windows Desktop Extension for UWP" but all those solutions will make the UWP app the main installation while Winforms will just be a secondary package that starts after the UWP app.

Is there a way to make the WinForms app as the main app and the UWP the extension?
I am trying to understand Wix but the documentation is outdated and i am not able to follow the documentation. I would like to avoid this dependency if possible.

I used this excellent guide by Stefan Wick but i need the opposite. I need the winform to be the main app and the installer to be a .exe file.

https://stefanwick.com/2017/06/24/uwp-app-with-systray-extension/

Comment: Extremely vague when you don't mention what UWP contract you want to use.  An example [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39141010/17034), the more up to date docs [are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance).

Comment: @HansPassant, i wanted to have a full UWP app that i can start from the Winforms app and have it do some actions such as sending toast notification or having a fancy UI while the Winforms will be used for system tray component and long running process. The solution in my question provide the opposite which force me to start UWP app at least once to start the winforms component which show the UWP splash screen and difficult to add to startup by default. Not to mention that UWP app is not friendly with AutoUpdate solution and installing it for LOB is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to create a WinForms application with UWP extension and not the opposite?

Currently, there is no such way to make UWP as extension for WinForms app, but you could use uwp feature in WinForms app like @Hans Passant said in the comment. And you could also use uwp control in your WinForms app, for more please refer [**Host a custom WinRT XAML control in a WPF app using XAML Islands**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-custom-control-with-xaml-islands).